# Type check fails for memberProperty returnType superclass

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I've got an instance of an object, which I scan for memberProperties that have a proper annotation attached on them. Then, I want to filter based on their return type.
For example if declaration is as follows: `class AutoValidatedThing : AutoValidatedUserInputComponent {...}` and the target instance contains a `@ValidComponent val someProperty: AutoValidatedThing = ...`, I'd want to get the `someProperty` as a `AutoValidatedUserInputComponent` to the end of the following code block:

```
    val invalidOnes = this::class.memberProperties
        .filter { it.javaField != null && it.javaField!!.isAnnotationPresent(ValidComponent::class.java) }
        .filter { val annotations = it.javaField?.annotations; annotations != null
                && annotations.map { ann -> ann.annotationClass }.contains(ValidComponent::class)
                && it.returnType is AutoValidatedUserInputComponent }
        .map { it.getter.call() as AutoValidatedUserInputComponent }
```

But `it.returnType is AutoValidatedUserInputComponent` ALWAYS returns false.

`AutoValidatedUserInputComponent` is a simple interface:

```
interface AutoValidatedUserInputComponent {
    fun blabla() : SomeType
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`returnType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-callable/return-type.html) on a `KProperty` doesn't return an instance with the given type that you could do an `is` check against - it returns a reflection class describing the type, specifically[`KType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-type/index.html), which of course does not implement your interface. Instead of using `is`, you can call [`isSubTypeOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/is-subtype-of.html) on it, and check if it's a subtype of another given `KType`.

For that call, you'll need to get a `KType` for your own interface - for this, you can use [`createType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-type.html) on its `KClass`:

```
val targetType = AutoValidatedUserInputComponent::class.createType(nullable = true)
```

The nullability part is up to you, and there are also other optional parameters for `createType`, if your interface would happen to have type parameters, for example.

Then, as I mentioned, you can use `isSubTypeOf`:

```
val invalidOnes = this::class.memberProperties
        .filter { it.javaField != null && it.javaField!!.isAnnotationPresent(ValidComponent::class.java) }
        .filter {
            val annotations = it.javaField?.annotations
            annotations != null
                    && annotations.map { ann -> ann.annotationClass }.contains(ValidComponent::class)
                    && it.returnType.isSubtypeOf(targetType)
        }
        .forEach {
            println("Found field with annotation and given supertype: $it")
        }
```